# Combine different procedures in python within a class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two classes in python and Need to recall different procedures within These classes.

```
class OpenWeatherMap():
    def __init__(self):
        self.fr='0'
        self.to='0'
        ...

     def getWeather(self):
     ...
         return WeatherList


class WeatherRecords():
     ...

     def allWeatherValues(self):
     ...
         return allSceneList
```

Then, within class WeatherRecords I need to use the allSceneList several times within other different procedures, for example:

```
def AddWeather(self):
            ...
            if any(weatherConditions in sl for sl in self.allWeatherValues())!=True:
                print('No such a weather condition in a list!')
                self.createAttrValue(weatherConditions)
            elif any(weatherConditions in sl for sl in self.allWeatherValues())==True:
                for j in range(len(self.allWeatherValues())):
                    if weatherConditions==self.allWeatherValues()[j][1]:
            ...
```

I don't want to recalculate this list several times (this is what I do by using self.allWeatherValues()), as it makes no sense. Can I define this as a global variable somehow, but such that my Code doesn't look to bad? Of Course, in the middle of my Code, between procedures, I could have writte something like this:

`allWeather=allWeatherValues()`,

but I've seen that others do not work like this. When I define main() and try to write my statement there, it also appears to be wrong:

```
def main():
    weather=Weather()
    weatherRecording=WeatherRecords()
    allWeather=weatherRecording.allWeatherValues()
    weatherRecording.AddWeather()
```

Can you please advise something reasonable in my case?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You just need an instance variable:

```
class WeatherRecords():
    def __init__(self):
        self.allSceneList = None
     ...

     def allWeatherValues(self):
        if self.allSceneList is None:
            # actually calculate allSceneList
            self.allSceneList = allSceneList
        return self.allSceneList
```

It starts set to `None`, but once calculated can just be returned.

Now you can call `weatherRecording.allWeatherValues()` wherever the list is needed.

There is also the handy side effect that if you never call this method, the calculation is never done.

Comment: This is great! Thank you very much! haven't seen anything like that in tutorials...

Comment: You need better tutorials.

Comment: Can you recommend something maybe?

Comment: Do you know anyone who is willing to pay for better tutorials?